# How do you return all the posible value in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, html

So i was wondering how do i shows the result once someone inputs the letter A.

the problem is it shows up for a few seconds and disapears

here's my code:

```js
function pop(){
    var text = document.getElementById('Search_Text').value;
    var res = text.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        switch(res[i]) {
            case "a":
                alert("a");
                break;
            case "A":
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="C";
                break;
         }
    }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="">
    <input type="text" id="Search_Text"></input>
    <button type="submit"onclick="pop()">change</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Do you have an idea, what submitting a form means?

Comment: A *for loop* does everything as fast as the processor will allow it, so if you're rendering to a page, it's going to be pretty fast. The `alert` will work because it pauses the script and waits for the user to continue.

Comment: teem you don't have to be rude, Im new here looking for help

Comment: @benji8 Me? By no means the comment wasn't meant to be rude ("any idea" might have been rude perhaps?). I've just asked you, whether you know what submitting a form means. I could count rude, that you didn't answer my question ; ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `submit` type button inside a `<form>` tag.

Clicking that button will cause the browser to reload the page.

Since there are many ways to stop this from happening ... One suggestion could be to put `return false;` inside the `onsubmit` attribute of the `<form>` tag:

`<form onsubmit="return false;">`

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you are submitting the form and the page reloads. Thats why you see the result only for a few seconds.

Try this:

```
function pop(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var text =document.getElementById('Search_Text').value;
    var res = text.split("");
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you've misunderstood the correct use of forms, and that what you're really trying to do is spit out letters individually onto a page after having typed into a text box and clicked the button.

A for loop does everything as fast as the processor will allow it, so if you're rendering to a page, it's going to be pretty fast.

If you want to see things clearly, you'll have to use JavaScript timing events with callbacks. Here's an example:

```js
function pop(){
  
  var text = document.getElementById('Search_Text').value;
  var res = text.split("");
  var element = document.getElementById("result");
  var duration = 500;
  
  showNextLetter();
  
  function showNextLetter () {
    
    if (res.length) {
      
      element.innerHTML += res.shift();
    
      setTimeout(showNextLetter, duration);
      
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form  onsubmit="">
<input type="text" id="Search_Text"></input>

<button type="submit"onclick="pop()">change</button>
</form>

<p id="result"></p>
```